# Wrong redirect from Hadoop HDFS NameNode to localhost:50075

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have installed apache hadoop on my virtual machine and configured it to run in pseudo distributed mode. Everything seems to work fine except one thing. I can list files and create folders using hadoop command line in my virtual machine.

When i open

```
http://192.168.20.200:50070 (virtual machine IP)
```

from my not virtual PC, i can see some NameNode information and link "Browse the filesystem". This link has following URL:

```
http://192.168.20.200:50070/nn_browsedfscontent.jsp
```

When i click it i'm being redirected to

```
http://localhost:50075/browseDirectory.jsp?namenodeInfoPort=50070&dir=/
```

If i replace "localhost" to "192.168.20.200" everything works.

core-sites.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost/</value>
  <description>...</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
  <description>Default block replication.</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
  <value>/app/hadoopstorage/name/</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
  <value>/app/hadoopstorage/data/</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried setting `fs.default.name` to `hdfs://192.168.20.200/`?

Comment: Yes, then i get redirect to http://no.local:50075/browseDirectory.jsp  or something like that

Comment: Sorry, not "no.local:50075", but "{nameOfMachine}.local:50075"

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems to work when my /etc/hosts file is like this

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   name1
192.168.20.200 192.168.20.200  <--- added this line
```

But it looks very strange. Is it right to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's common in the Hadoop ecosystem for services to get and report back the loopback adapter address `127.0.0.1 (localhost)` if the `HOSTNAME` is specified in the HOSTS file on the wrong IP address.

If you are going this route with the `/etc/hosts` file, make sure that only 'localhost' or 'localhost.localdomain' is present on the `::1` or `127.0.0.1` lines.